# git is ignoring the 'git add' command'

Tags: git

I'm on windows 10 and I'm trying to add some changes to a file to a branch.

I'm going:

```
git add aws_ec2_list_instances.py
```

And when I got git status nothing is added:

```
$ git status
On branch python
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   __pycache__/web_scraper.cpython-37.pyc
        modified:   __pycache__/web_scraper.cpython-38.pyc
        modified:   aws_s3_list_buckets.py
        modified:   web_scraper.py

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        ../../output_files/
        aws_ec2_list_instances_old.py
        ../../source_files/

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Doing a `git add --all` or `git add --force` gives the same result. Nothing is added!

If I list the directory `aws_ec2_list_instances.py` is there:

```
git ls-files
__pycache__/web_scraper.cpython-37.pyc
__pycache__/web_scraper.cpython-38.pyc
aws_ec2_list_instances.py
aws_s3_list_buckets.py
web_scraper.py
```

I'm on this version of git for windows: `git version 2.24.1.windows.2`

How can I solve this?

Comment: Does `aws_ec2_list_instances.py` have any changes? What do you see when you run `git diff -- aws_ec2_list_instances.py`?

Comment: Either `aws_ec2_list_instances.py` is the same as what is already committed or it is listed in `.gitignore`.

Comment: It's not listed in git ignore. And there are definitely changes to the file. I'm even adding arbitrary changes just to be sure. `git add aws_ec2_instances.py` does nothing when I do a git status.

Comment: There are seven paths listed in your `git status` output, four under `changes not staged for commit` and three under `untracked files`. None of these seven exactly match the string `aws_ec2_list_instances.py`. So I would not expect `git add` to do anything here. Separately: You can view what's in the index (ALL of it, it will be very long in most cases) with `git ls-files`, or `git ls-files --stage` or `git ls-files --debug` for extra detail.

Comment: You might also try `git show HEAD:./aws_ec2_list_instances.py` to see what's in *that* copy of the file, if it exists at all, and `git show :./aws_ec2_list_instances.py` to see what's in the *index* copy of the file, if it exists at all. My guess is that both files exist and are identical to each other *and* to the copy in `./aws_ec2_list_instances.py`.

Comment: If I do 'git ls-files` the file `aws_ec2_list_instances.py` is there. I have updated the OP to show that.

Comment: Yes, the file is there, but _it is unchanged_. Computers don't lie.

Comment: No. The file has changed. I tried putting in `print('Test'`)` in the file and copied it several times and saved it. When I do a `git add` to the file and then a `git status` it does not show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The file has changed. I tried putting in print('Test')` in the file and copied it several times and saved it.

Then you have tried to modified a different aws_ec2_list_instances.py, in a different path.
Double-check your editor (VSCode?) and see if:

- the path is correct
- the case is correct
- it is able to actually save the file (which might refuse new modification if its handle is used by another Windows process)

Answer (score 0):

Your file name doesn't seem to match the file names that needed to be added. If you want to add all your changes then just use `git add .` command

I would recommend installing github desktop. It is easy and more convenient to use than using the command line.

Comment: Your first statement is correct, but the underlying issue is probably not that.